# whats wrong with my php mail() function

Tags: php

Am not having good knowledge in PHP, I have just started to work on it...
Now am trying to use mail() function as example given in w3schools.com

```
<?php
$to = "ramkumarpece05@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "ramp211087@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

for this am getting error message as follows

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify
your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in F:\contact.ph
p on line 7
Mail Sent.
```

where the php.ini file is located or i have to download it from the internet.....

Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: `php.ini` is some configuration file on the web server.

Comment: you should take a look at the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see where your php.ini file is located. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Generally this won't work on your own (local/home) computer because your computer is not set to work as a mail server. To test this out, you must either have a computer that is configured as one or use a live server

Comment: or you can configure your local system to use your public smtp-server to send mails.

Comment: good tutorial: http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Comment: Ha Ha... Try this code in Server...

Comment: @suresh.g: I cant get you, can you please explain....

Comment: Upload your PHP file to server and run your code. Surely it will send mail. In Localhost we cant send mail.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't install a mail server on your machine, you can install [one](http://www.smartertools.com/free-editions.aspx) for testing purposes (mail from your server will probably be marked as spam) or [you can configure PHP to use your email account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page).

Answer (score 1):

Your mail method is fine, your local server isn't. It is attempting to send the email but there is no SMTP server setup on your local server to send the email. You can install programs like Tomcat or Mercury which can handle the sending of the emails. You will just have to provide it some credentials to authenticate. I used my Gmail account's SMTP for example to send emails from my local server.